# Slow wireless about 1/3 bandwidth of wired from cable modem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, router

HP DV6000 Wireless G Broadcom

Netgear WNDR3400 router properly configured.

Windows laptops using wireless G and N are considerably faster than mine.

12.04 LTS, all restricted drivers and all up to date.

50Mbps wired and 9-21 Mbps wireless on Ubuntu.

```
00:14.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller [10de:0269] (rev a3)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Presario V6133CL [103c:30b7]
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadcom 802.11a/b/g WLAN [103c:1370]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question.

Comment: Thanks. The wireless is a BCM4311, so you may want to try another driver. Check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/38700/20054) for info on installing it.